# Issue with loading files into dist folder

Tags: angular

How do I populate the dist folder in my angular2 app? I was under the impression it got automagically populated when building the app with npm but the only file that gets added is webpack-assets.json. I need other files like main.bundle.js and the other js and html files necessary to run my app to be built into dist

The angular2 starter I am using is https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your app in a local server with

```
npm run server
```

but to automagically populate the */dist* folder you use the **build** command:

```
# development
npm run build:dev
# production (jit)
npm run build:prod
# AoT
npm run build:aot
```

Comment: I tried that several times last night and the only file that was getting recreated in dist was webpack-assets.json

Comment: Any other ideas? If this is how it is supposed to work then I'll just try a different starter... maybe I hosed something up on accident when I was tinkering

Comment: Sorry @Joff, it's tough to tell what's wrong without seeing the full source code. If it's a public project can you post a link to the repo?